# Is there a way to control windows in another Java process?

Tags: java, swing, security, process

I have a java Swing program that sometimes have to restart itself without user's intervention. The problem is that I have to give a new instance created with

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar " + applicationJarPath, previousCommandLineArguments);
```

a user name and his password to be used for automatic login process. And neither login nor password cannot be transferred as a command line arguments (for security reasons). The same goes for files or anything that is not in-memory. I could use sockets, but this could create another possible security hole (if somebody connects to the same port that the previous instance waiting on).

So I was thinking about printing user name and password into the appropriate controls.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to somehow find and control Swing controls in another instance of the same app?
2. If this is not possible (or fairly difficult) is there a way to securely pass a user name and a password to another instance of a program?

Comment: *"I have a java Swing program that sometimes have to restart itself.."* Why does it need to restart?

Comment: So you don't want to use sockets, command line parameters or files because it might represent a security risk, but you want to be able to inject input into a separate process remotely ... And you don't see that as a security risk? You could use Robot, but it's troublesome as you need to be able to get the right fields focused and that's tricky when you can't inspect controls of the window. You could generate a encrypted file which contains the credentials

Comment: Encrypted file is actually the option that me and our team stopped at. It is a security risk, but we know the possible impact and it is easy to maintain in the future (and there is a lower chance of finding bugs in that code). Sorry for a late answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern operating systems are designed to prevent processes from accessing one another.  There are various inter-process communications (IPC) or remote procedure call (RPC) mechanisms to allow this in a limited and controlled way, but the programs have to intentionally use them.  In other words, your program has to be listening for the message.  You can't just arbitrarily access some other program.

You can find a long list of possible solutions by searching for [java rpc](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+rpc).  There are different options on Java-based platforms like Android.  You could also roll your own with TCP sockets or something.

Incidentally, if you're worried about security, the first instance of the program shouldn't be holding onto the password in the first place.

Comment: We stopped at encrypted file option. I didn't like at first, but me and our team leader agreed that this is the best option from maintenance point of view (how knows how this code is going to change in the future).